# Різниця між словами "любов" та "кохання"

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

В англійській мові є лише слово *love* для позначення відчуттів як до батьків та друзів, так і до коханої людини. Тому фразу *I love you* слід перекладати відповідно до контексту, залежно до кого відбувається звернення.

В іспанській мові так само є іменник *el amor*, який вживається в обох випадках. У польській мові ситуація аналогічна зі словом *miłość* (принаймні, так каже гугл-перекладач), в німецькій - *die Liebe*, в російській - *любовь*.

Як правильно пояснити іноземцям різницю між українськими словами *любов* та *кохання*?

Знаю, що в іспанській *Te quiero* кажуть батькам та друзям, а *Te amo* коханим. У польській навпаки - для обох випадків вживають *Kocham cię*. У яких іще мовах відрізняються фрази *Я тебе люблю* і *Я тебе кохаю*?

І чи коректно казати *Я тебе люблю* коханій дівчині? Чи не є це применшенням відчуттів?

Comment: ваше питання дуже розфокусоване. Підзапитання "У яких іще мовах відрізняються фрази `Я тебе люблю` і `Я тебе кохаю`?" взагалі не стосується української мови (хоча є досить цікавим), тож не є релевантним для цього сайту.

Comment: Згоден. Це підзапитання не стосується теми, але, можливо, хтось принагідно поділиться знаннями з цього приводу, відповідаючи на основне запитання.

Comment: Заради справедливості треба сказати, що в англійській мові для людських почуттів використовується й "like". Достатньо в Google написати запит `I like you but I don't love you`

Comment: "Люблю тебе, моя кохана" - співають [Дзідзьо](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/DZIDZIO) у пісні ["108"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gajKZUL4yek)

Comment: Кохання, на відміну від любові, включає пристрасть. У словнику Б. Грінченка кохання це:

1. любов, любовна пристрасть;
2. улюблений предмет, коханий або кохана;
3. виховання, плекання, вирощування (дітей, тварин, рослин)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

На [укрмові](http://ukrmova.in.ua) є досить розгорнуте пояснення:

[Кохати і любити](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/sunonimu/koxatu-j-lyubutu):

> Кохати – 1. Почувати глибокі сердечні (романтичні) почуття до особи, здебільшого протилежної статі. Приклади: «Так ніхто не кохав, через тисячі літ лиш приходить подібне кохання» (Володимир Сосюра). 2. Плекати, вирощувати щось. Приклади: «Лукаш усе садовину ростив та кохав» (Марко Вовчок), «Доню моя, доню моя, цвіте мій рожевий! Як ягідку, як пташечку, кохала, ростила на лишенько…» (Тарас Шевченко).
>
> Любити – 1. Почувати глибоку відданість, прихильність до когось, чогось, мати інтерес, потяг до чогось. Приклади: «Любіть Україну, як сонце, любіть, як вітер, і трави, і води… » (Володимир Сосюра), «Терентій любить пісню і сам уміє з душею співати» (Михайло Стельмах). 2. Потребувати якихось умов для існування. Приклад: «Виноград любить, щоб коло нього ходити» (Михайло Коцюбинський).

Отже:

> Кохати можна: Наталю, Павла, чоловіка, дружину, хлопця etc.
>
> Любити можна: Україну, сина, маму, подорожі, борщ etc.

Від себе додам, що в слові "кохати" є більше пристрасті, аніж у слові "любити". Не думаю, що "люблю" якимось чином применшуватиме почуття, просто відводитиме акцент з пристрасті на любов більш широку, аніж кохання.

Answer (score 8):

[Грінченко](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/24389-kokhaty.html#show_point) в тлумаченні слова «кохати» не робить ніякого «статевого» відтінку:

> Кохати, -ха́ю, -єш, гл. 1) Любить (кого-либо). Ой ти, дівчино, мислоньками блудиш, сама ти не знаєш, кого вірно любиш. Ой знаю, знаю, кого я кохаю, тілько я не знаю, із ким жити маю. Н. п. Хто вірно кохає, той часто вітає. Ном. №8757. *Батько й мати твої живуть при тобі і дякують... що ти їх при старости й кохаєш* і поважаєш. Кв. 2) Взлелѣивать, возрощать, воспитывать (о дѣтяхъ, животныхъ, растеніяхъ). Кошару дитину кохала, любила, — крій себе не маю. Макс. Ой косо, косо, кохана, сім літ я тебе кохала! Мет. 205. Cм. викохати

З іншого боку, в сучасних джерелах «кохати» набуло відтінку саме кохання між чоловіком та жінкою.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "кохання" вживається для опису стосунків між чоловіком та жінкою зі статевим відтінком. Слово "любов" - для опису будь-яких ніжних почуттів.

Доволі прикро визнати, але всі тлумачні словники української мови які зараз доступні, є, по суті, копіями 11-томного "Словника української мови" виданого в 1970-80рр. Цей словник дає означення слова "[любов](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljubov)" як "Почуття глибокої сердечної прихильності до особи іншої статі; [кохання](http://sum.in.ua/s/kokhannja)" і не роз'яснює змістовних відмінностей між цими словами.

В той самий час слова "любити" і "кохати" в тлумачних словниках справді різняться.

Comment: Власне, я з Вами цілком згоден. Але хорошими вважаються **аргументовані** відповіді. Чи Ви можете її якось підтвердити (посиланням на словник, цитатами з художніх творів тощо)?

Comment: Доволі прикро визнати, але всі тлумачні словники української мови які зараз доступні, є, по суті, копіями 11-томного "Словника української мови" виданого в 1970-80рр. Цей словник дає означення слова "любов" як "Почуття глибокої сердечної прихильності до особи іншої статі; кохання" і не роз'яснює змістовних відмінностей між цими словами.
Тобто **моя відповідь суперечить написаному в тлумачних словниках**, але я все одно вважаю, що приведені означення найбільш коротко й точно описують значення слів в сучасній мові.

Comment: Чому ж? Он подивіться статтю [кохати](http://sum.in.ua/s/kokhaty): 1. Почувати, виявляти глибоку сердечну прихильність до особи іншої статі. 2. рідко. Те саме, що *любити 1* (тобто: Відчувати глибоку відданість, прив'язаність до кого-, чого-небудь). 3. Дбайливо вирощувати, плекати що-небудь, ходити коло чогось.

Comment: А тепер статтю [любити](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljubyty) — там є в тому числі: 3. також з інфін. Мати інтерес, потяг до чого-небудь («Я страшенно люблю читати»). //  Високо цінувати що-небудь, надавати перевагу чомусь. //  з інфін., з додатком і без нього. Відчувати задоволення від чого-небудь. // з інфін. із додатком. Мати нахил, пристрасть до чого-небудь. // 4. також із спол. щоб. Потребувати якихось умов як найсприятливіших для існування, росту тощо (про рослини, тварин) («Виноград любить, щоб коло нього ходити»).

Comment: Так, Ви праві, слова "любити" і "кохати" в тлумачних словниках справді різняться. (На відміну від слів [любов](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljubov) і [кохання](http://sum.in.ua/s/kokhannja))

Comment: То ж він, ясно, не ідеальний, але якщо ретельно вдивитись, то можна помітити, що, наприклад, можна любити бутерброди з ковбасою — а кохати вже якось не дуже. Хоча, звісно, всіх відтінків значень він не передасть і далі вже доведеться додати від себе. А іноді — й лише від себе, якщо тема така, що в словниках пусто. Але, якщо є можливість, краще ж, звісно, на щось опиратися.

Comment: Так, я [любов](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljubov) і [кохання](http://sum.in.ua/s/kokhannja) бачив. Але там теж є різниця, хоч і не така значна. Наприклад, любов має "3. до чого. Інтерес до чого-небудь.", і також любов має "2. Почуття глибокої сердечної прив'язаності до кого-, чого-небудь" (а про кохання сказано "2. **рідко**. Те саме, що *любов 2*"). Окрім того, кохання має "3. Дія або стан за знач. кохати 1, 3 і кохатися".

Comment: Власне, я **не кажу**, що треба передирати СУМ. Але **хоч щось** треба навести, хоча б для вигляду. Хоча б цитати з творів. Хоча й це не всюди працює.

Comment: Якщо донька каже батькові: «я тебе кохаю». Що він має відповісти?:)